# RLC or LC and why

Tags: resonance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1FNZF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've run in to some trouble, working out wether i need to use a RLC or just a LC tank for my circuit.
My circuit is an H-bridge, where i need to use either LC or RLC on the output, to make a sine wave. Do you guys or gals and any tips or tricks, or just simple explaining to me, why one is better than the other.
//Thanks!

Comment: With every L comes an R so, your question is *RLC or RLC?* basically.

Comment: If it's from an ideal POV, the R is just dissipative, OTOH you'll need some load, but that comes across the cap, but then both L and C may have their series or parallel resistance... I think what I'm trying to say is that you gave precious little information. What tank? What H-bridge? I suppose switching regime, then what frequency for the carrier and the signal? What is "better"? etc

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my question and added a schematic, where V1 is the signal coming from the H-bridge. R1 is a load, and the place i need to transfer all the power. I have no idea though, wether i should use a resistor on the left side, or just keep it with just a LC.